# How to write a dataframe table to excel in R

Tags: r, excel, dataframe, csv, write.table

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
TIME      Type    A      B      C
15:15:00  Alpha   5      3      1
...       ...     ...    ...    ...
```

I tried: `write.table(data, file="data.csv", col.names=TRUE)` but it did not work. All I get is that the data for each row is completely in the first cell of each row.

The row with TIME, Type, A, B, C should be HEADER or the names of the column  and separate the data down below.

Any suggestions?
Thank you!

Comment: Side note: Excel is not CSV. Excel happens to be able to open CSV files, but it is *not* CSV.

Comment: There are packages `writexl` or `openxlsx` that provide functions like `write_xlsx` or `write.xlsx`.

Comment: What do you see if you open the CSV file in a text editor like Notepad, and not in Excel? This seems like an issue in Excel, not in the output.

Comment: Thanks. Opening it in a txt-editor I see the data separated like I wanted. Any ideas how I can fix the issue in Excel?

Comment: *Import* the data in Excel, instead of just clicking on the CSV to open it. And to add to my first comment, Excel happens to be able to open CSV files, but not very well, as you're experiencing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
install.packages("openxlsx", dependencies = TRUE)

openxlsx::write.xlsx(data, "data.xlsx")
```